# java exception java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm basically trying to end the program only when the user enter zero, else keep looping in input for processing.

I have a question on what's going on, whenever I try to compile it, it keeps giving me an error like this:

> Expected Output   Your Output 1   16  1            Exception in thread
>   "main"java.util.InputMismatchException 2  Tom 69.28   2      at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909) 3    Mickey 108.42   3      at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530) 4   Juliet 2488.71  4      at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160) 5    Ann 2201.94     5      at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119) 6    Christy 894.14  6      at
>   Bank.main(Bank.java:103)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 // declare the necessary variables
 double x;
 int p; 
 double balance;

 String name; 
 List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

 // declare a Scanner object to read input
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
 // read input and process them accordingly
 x = sc.nextDouble();
 p = sc.nextInt(); 

 // while (sc.hasNext() == true)
 String action;
 // {
 do {
 action = sc.next();

 //ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); 

 if (action.equals("Create"))
 {
 do something
 }

 if (action.equals("Withdraw"))
 {

 {
 do something

 }
 }

 }


 if (action.equals("Deposit"))
 {



 // output the result
         }


 if (action.equals("0"))
 {

 System.out.println(list.size());
 for(Person d : list){
 double bal = d.getBalance(); 

 System.out.println(d.getName());

 }     }

 }

 while ( /*action != null &&*/ !action.isEmpty());
 }
 }
```

Comment: Have you declared x and p as being double and int, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Looking at your stacktrace:

> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160) 5 Ann 2201.94 5 at

That means whatever you are inputting is not an integer.

```
p = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: but my input is 13, which is an integer and even if i changed the scanner method to nextDouble(); i am still having the same compilation error.

Comment: Can you paste the entire input?

Comment: i managed to solve it, you were right. the input was not an int! thank you so much!